# Problems writing too much custom controls in WPF

Tags: wpf, mvvm, wpf-controls

I am working on new WPF/MVVM project, where I see all most all controls are written for different needs, right from textbox to treeview. All are rewritten for simple need, for example, grid,stackpanel control are rewritten to add space between each item and textbox is rewritten to include label for it so that it has both label and text input are on itself.

My question : Is there any serious issue we would encounter because of this customization? 
Already, I am seeing issues with aligning all controls, will i would see any more issues because of this?.

Comment: When you say "rewritten," do you mean "you have custom code to reimplement each control," or "you have custom styles for each control?" Or do you just mean that there are a lot of custom controls in the project and that you're not really "rewriting" the existing controls?

Comment: I mean re-implement each control with added properties or functionality and also, restyling controls (i mean overwriting its control templates)

Comment: you have to choose the correct controls when you're developing. Some controls take into account alignment of the container they are in, some don't.  Some have a `HorizontalContentAlignment` and some have just `HorizontalAlignment`. If you want to add "XAML properties" then you only need to implement a dependency property for that control.  WPF is nothing like WinForms, so writing custom controls doesn't happen very often.

Comment: NETscape, I agree with you, I had a same doubt, as WPF offers most of the properties. The reason give by my architect is, 1. this would help displaying validation errors properly, 2. we do our own alignment and styling. Now, my problem is, will it have any effect on the performance of the application over all.

Comment: @Senthilkumar: Tell your architect to read more about Styles and Themes. It provides what he is looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never create a custom or user control to add margins, a label to a TextBox, or a new `ItemTemplate` to a `ListBox`.

UserControls are for grouping frequently used combinations of controls into one reuseable control. An example may be a custom List-of-Values control that opens a dialog. This would be fine to implement as a `UserControl`.

Custom controls are good when a native control does not suit your needs. Say that you want to reimplement a DateTimePicker from scratch because the native one doesn't include milliseconds.

There are no serious issues as such, but you may find yourself maintaining all these controls for the next many years without there being a need to do so.

Settings Margins should be done in the `View` where you are using it, or on a `Style` in a `ResourceDictionary`.

This is of course only my opinion (and that of many others, I except), but if you find that the majority of your controls are 'customized' this way, you are doing it wrong.

`Style` and `Templates` rather than `UserControls` and custom controls.

The main issue is that you lose the ability to alter margins only in a single view. If you change your custom controls' inner paddings and margins, you will be changing all the views in your solution. If you use a style, you can always override it by defining a new style in the view, or by setting the property directly.

Comment: Do you see any performance bottlenecks? or any kind of memory leak it might cause?. I see lot of good features in vs2013, will I be able to use those feature (like, intellisense in xaml binding and resource mapping, memory management techniques) if I use custome controls.

Comment: @Senthilkumar: You are making the Visual Tree larger by adding more controls. That will decrease performance slightly. Intellisense and bindings will work as normal. You will just be writing a lot of extra code that serves no purpose. Memory Leaks in WPF mostly occur (by my experience) from event subscriptions that are not correctly unsubscribed. My main issue with this approach is not performance, it is having to maintain this afterwards. You are creating controls for the only purpose of declaring styles. This is what Styles are for.

Comment: @Troles, Thanks for your answer and time. I have got no choice than getting used to with this approach, I just wanna to check whether it is good approach or not.

Comment: @csensoft: Well, I feel sorry for you :) I have worked with WPF for the last 7 years, and I have never heard of anyone taking this approach. Nor can I see a reason to do so.

Comment: @Troles, yup, I also have 5 years of experience I have never created more than few custom controls (only for specific need and its not part of WPF library) ..